# Using a cell reference inside a function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm putting together a worksheet that uses a dropdown to choose a value from a predefined list. The list is a series of YYYYMM values. I'm trying to take the selected value in the dropdown cell and use it in a file name inside of a VLOOKUP, see below:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E$2,'/Monthly Reports/[Joe's Company - [cell reference value] Profit and Loss Standard.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1:$E$100,3,FALSE),0)
```

In this example, [cell reference value] is 202301. Now I want to use that value to define a filename that resides in a folder and run a VLOOKUP against that file. I'm unable to get that value to show as 202301, to show up as a value rather than text. I'm missing something probably simple.

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would use INDIRECT to wrap the concatenated text string to return an actual reference to the formula.  But realize that INDIRECT will require that the target file be open.

Comment: Scott, can you show me how that would work in my example? Where does that INDIRECT go?

Comment: What scott said, plus (per your edit) if you are having issues with the formatting you will either need to convert the value to text, or text to value. For example `VALUE($E$2)`.

Comment: `INDIRECT("'/Monthly Reports/[Joe's Company - ["&cell reference value&"] Profit and Loss Standard.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$1:$E$100")` inside the VLOOKUP